# Android : Change the background when clicked on spinner

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-spinner

I have 3 spinner for country, timezone and language with the respective labels arranged one below another in below manner

```
Label1  Spinner1
Label2  Spinner2
Label3  Spinner3
```

When Click on say `Spinner1`, I want entire row i.e. Label and spinner to change their background color, Say if I take it in a LinearLayout So on spinner click The background should change to blue

I want probably a xml way of changing background of whole layout and not programmatic as I will have to code for each spinner

Can someone tell me how do I change entire layout color on just spinner click

I tried `Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener`, but that is hitting only when I select some item, but I want the layout to change color even on press of `Spinner`

Spinner in layout 
layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlay"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"

                android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner_pressed">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/label"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Label"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="14dp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:popupBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Settings.java file

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Log.e("Techie","----------------------------citizenship1----------------------------");

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    Log.e("Techie","----------------------------citizenship2----------------------------");

                }
            });
```

I expect the Layout with id linearlay should change its primary color white to change to Blue on spinner click. please help

Answer (score 0):

Call setonTouchListener and handle down and up events to change the colors

```
spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            Log.e("Techie", "----------------------------Action down----------------------------");
                            layout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.color1));
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            Log.e("Techie", "----------------------------Cancel----------------------------");
                            layout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.color2));
                            break;
                    }

                    // allow target view to handle click
                    return false;
                }

            });
```